# OpenCL source code?

Tags: frameworks, opencl

I would like to take a look on how the OpenCL framework is implemented. All I find are libraries that are already compiled available for download.

Surely there can be many different implementations of OpenCL, but I would like to take a look at one of those to learn how its done.

Just to make sure I make myself clear, by OpenCL framework I mean the part that manages platforms, devices, command queues, etc.

Thank you!

Comment: Thats propietary software. And is part of the drivers of each manuafacturer.

Comment: you may find a list of open source implemetations [here](https://github.com/fakenmc/cf4ocl/wiki/OpenCL-implementations)

Answer (score 2):

Many implementations are closed-source proprietary software that comes with the video card drivers.  But there are a couple of open source ones that I know of:

- [Beignet](http://wiki.freedesktop.org/www/Software/Beignet/) - an OpenCL implementation for Intel Ivy Bridge.  Source code [here](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/beignet/).
- [Pocl](http://pocl.sourceforge.net/) - uses LLVM.

I don't know how complete the implementations are, but might be enough to start you off.  Both seem to have active development.

Comment: I forgot there were some open source implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Other open source implementations:
[Clover in mesa](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/clover/), [FreeOCL](https://code.google.com/p/freeocl/) and [COPRTHR](http://www.browndeertechnology.com/coprthr.htm) and its [Parallella fork](https://github.com/parallella/coprthr)